# Removing object from realm in swiftUI gives error 'Object has been deleted or invalidated.'

Tags: ios, swift, realm, swiftui

So, I am trying to build *clean swift* architecture app with swiftUI. And my task is to achieve a single source of truth, so I use dependency injection. I request realm data in my appState.userData class and then trying to use this array in my view. Problem appears when I'm trying to delete object from realm. **Item gets deleted but then  'Object has been deleted or invalidated.' error appears**

```
class AppState {
    var userData = UserData()
}

extension AppState {
    class UserData: ObservableObject {

        @Published var places:[Place]
        var realm: Realm!
        private var placesToken: NotificationToken?

        init(){
            realm = try! Realm()
            places = Array(realm.objects(Place.self))
            activateChannelsToken()
        }

        private func activateChannelsToken() {
            let realm = try! Realm()
            let places = realm.objects(Place.self)
            placesToken = places.observe {[weak self] _ in
                self?.places = Array(places)

            }
        }

        deinit {
            placesToken?.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

Deleting func looks like this

```
func deletePlace(with id: String){
        if let objectToDelete = realm.object(ofType: Place.self, forPrimaryKey: id), !objectToDelete.isInvalidated {
            try? realm.write {
                realm.delete(objectToDelete)
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying get item by primary key, but I tried many other options like sending oject to func etc. Doesnt matter how I get objec, I still get that error.

And in my view I read data this way:

```
struct PlacesList: View {
    @Environment(\.injected) private var injected: DIContainer

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(injected.appState.userData.places){ place in
                        PlaceRow(place: place)
                    }
                }
......
```

I suppose this is due to the way the swiftUI behaves, I think it’s trying to read an object that is already deleted or something like that.
I hope somebody have some ideas how to fix this issue.

**Note: I really need solution that doesn't brake architecture**

Comment: can you show us the code for Places? It should be inheriting `Identifiable` so ForEach knows its a dynamic list

Comment: The code is a bit hard to decipher; that may be part of the issue. Keep in mind that realm objects are live updating; meaning that if a Results object contains an object and that object is deleted, it's also deleted from the results. But. You are going around that functionality by converting realm results into arrays. By doing that you're loosing the live updating aspect of those objects as well as gobbling up memory as they are no longer lazily loaded. Also, this code `self?.places = Array(places)` is called when there's a change which is recursively assigning places back to places.

Comment: You shouldn't be using arrays, they are not live updating. You delete an object from realm but it still exists in the array. The problem lies in the fact that SwiftUI is trying to access those objects which are no longer valid.