# Delete Realm Object in SwiftUI NavigationLink View

Tags: swiftui, realm, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

i'm having a list view, row view (for each element in the list) and detail view (which will be opened by a NavigationLink in the row view).
In the detail view i have a delete button where i'm trying to delete the realm object and go back to the list view, but i receive following error at the top of AppDelegate:

***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object has been deleted or invalidated.'***

Detail View (in simple):

```
struct TransactionDetailView: View {
    
    let realm = try! Realm()
    `Realm Objects which contains some information (title, value ...). Can be null, if the user creates a new one`
    @State var transaction: MyTransaction?
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {...}
                   .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                     Button(action: {
                       if(self.transaction != nil) {
                         try! realm.write {
                           realm.delete(self.transaction!)
                         }
                       }
                       `If i remove this line and go manual back to the list view i have no issues`
                       self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                       Image(systemName: "trash")
                    })
}
```

The List and Row View (in simple):

```
struct TransactionsView: View {
    
    //get the DB
    let realm = try! Realm()
    
    //get the observable transactions
    @ObservedObject var transactions = BindableResults(results: try! Realm().objects(MyTransaction.self))
    
    var body: some View {
      ...
      List {
        ForEach(transactions) { transaction in
          TransactionRow(transaction: transaction, ...)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

```
struct TransactionRow: View {
    var transaction: MyTransaction
    ...
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: TransactionDetailView(transaction: transaction)){...}
        ...
    }
}
```

I don't see my problem why it doesn't work, but when i only delete the object and close the detail view manual all would be fine.

Thanks for your help

Comment: See my comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62231828/removing-object-from-realm-in-swiftui-gives-error-object-has-been-deleted-or-in) noting the issues with Arrays. Also what's this `BindableResults` and why are you using it?

Comment: Thx, i missed the point with the Arrays. In the DB is a plain list with all transactions but in the view i want to show the transactions structured in months & weeks. So i got the transactions and structured it in some arrays (not part of the code snippet).
Now i changed the code structure and work direct with the realm results and doesn't make the structure in arrays with the realm objects. Now all is working. 
BindableResults was an intermediate class which solves a part of the problems, but now i doesn't need it longer and the code is cleaner.